# Prove that $(2,\sqrt{65})$ is not principal in the number ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{65})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

> The number ring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{65})$ is $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2}\right]$. I want to prove that the ideal $(2,\sqrt{65})$ is not a principal ideal.

If $(2,\sqrt{65})=(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{O}$, then $2=||(2,\sqrt{65})||=||(\alpha)||=|N(\alpha)|$. I also know that $N(\alpha)=a^2+ab-16b^2$. So I have to prove that
$$a^2+ab-16b^2=\pm2$$
doesn't have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$. How can I do this?

Comment: In fact, your ideal is the unit ideal $(1)$, principal. You probably meant to ask about $\bigl(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{65}}2\bigr)$ or something like this.